# docker image run in Visual studio not the same as it run from cmd

Tags: visual-studio, docker, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I see some changes when running my docker image inside VS, and when it's run from the cmd.

for example - Console.ReadLine() inside VS work for me as a way to save some connection open (also when I run it in "Realese" mode), but once I using visual studio auto generated dockerfile, to build an image and run it from the cmd, the Console.ReadLine() not working and the connection close immediately.

now, my question is - how can I run the docker image exactly the same in VS like in cmd?

thank you